# In azure how can I get the storage costs per container in data lakes

Tags: azure

I am trying to get a report on the cost per container in Azure datalakes across the organisation, is there a query/workbook/power bi report that can give me this information

I have tried looking at cost analysis with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You may utilize Blob inventory to determine the size of the blobs within the container, and subsequently, you can calculate the costs using the Azure pricing calculator.

Blob inventory: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/calculating-container-level-stats-in-azure-blob-storage/ba-p/3064312